# How do I transfer Ether from multiple account to one account?

Tags: ether, wallets

I have a vast amount of Ethereum wallets, all packed with Ether. I need to transfer all the Ether to a single account. I don't want to do it manually. Is there a way to script it or use a smart contract or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

There is going to be a level of manual work that will be unavoidable since each wallet will need to be recognized and unlocked via a private key.

You could use web3 and some sort of key/value formatted data and loop through that to unlock and send the ether balance (minus gas) to whatever account you want to send it too.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about. I have a csv file with the public keys of the wallets. So I would first go and check the balance and calculate the gas, as I want to fully withdraw everything from the wallets. Than I would use my list with privat and public keys to generate the transactions and to sign them. Do you think this should work this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web3js or web3py, as you do not seem to have the accounts linked to a node with a json file per account, you can use web3 to get the balance of each account then build the transaction locally, sign it with the corresponding private_key and send sendRawTransaction. Then repeat for every account.

You can see how to sign using your private key and send raw transactions [here](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar sort of situation. I have an HD wallet and many of the child addresses will have Ethereum. So my plan is:

Loop through each index (address) in the HD wallet and check the balance. If the balance is found create a send transaction with a locally signed and keep it in memory. At the end of processing, send all the transactions as a batch to an Ethereum node.

Is this the right/best approach?

I am creating a crypto exchange and I am giving each customer a address from my HD wallet (using index) and so I can recover all eth from HD wallet which will have eth from multiple customers. Please suggest, if this is the right approach?